# Cannot boot a Linux VM Over VirtualBox on Windows 10

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

**Environment:**  Windows 10

Scenario: Trying to spin up a Linux VM on VirtualBox (Version 6.0.8 r130520 (Qt5.6.2))
Tried the following vms:

- CentOS
- Ubuntu
- Arch-OS

The settings seem to be fine.
I get the following consistent UI display:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is host Windows?  Do they all hang on *"Loading initial ramdisk ..."*?

Comment: Yes thats right. I am actually at a loss on how to troubleshoot the issue.    Note: I don't have the Guest Addition Add On which has been recommended.

Comment: Are you trying to boot in EFI mode (in Virtualbox settings)?  Arch takes a long time at this point - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_guests

Comment: Can you give some more details about the issue: your actions, display messages, what exactly went not as expected?